# Get comment of requested approval in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-pages, power-automate

I'm trying to get the comment which you can leave when you submit a modern page for approval.

[image: Submit for approval]

But if I use "Comments associated with moderation of list item", I get no result!

[image: Power Automate]

How do I get this comment? Is the dynamic content "Comments associated with moderation of list item" right? Or do I need to use a other dynamic content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit the view of the site pages, you will find Approver comments and Check in Comment. The dynamic content "Comments associated with moderation of list item" is Approver comments. The Check in Comment is what you want. And per my test, there is no dynamic contents represent the Check in Comment. To get this comment, you may need to send Http request to SharePoint to get this comment.

[image]

Updated:

Uri:`_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<listName>')/items(<id>)/versions`

Headers: `content-type`  `application/json;odata=verbose`

[image]

Filter array Expression:

```
body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')['d']['results']

item()['OData__x005f_CheckinComment']

null
```

Email body:

```
body('Filter_array')[0]['OData__x005f_CheckinComment']
```

[image]

Test results:

[image]

Reference:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/SharePoint-How-to-get-Check-in-Comment/td-p/354958

Comment: So my question remains, how can I use it in my Flow? How can I send a Http request and where to?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much - this is what I am looking for and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

(I am new so would have added this as a comment if I could)

The trigger of the Approval when setup through the PowerAutomate section on site pages adds an additional input parameter of message as default. This could be the dynamic value you are after?

[image]

[image]